# C# get windows drive hardware caption via registry

Tags: c#, key, registry, partial

I need to retrieve the name of drive where Windows is installed.
Best way I found to do it is via registry, since WMI is very slow for this specific query.

```
string diskdrive = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 0\Scsi Bus 0\Target Id 0\Logical Unit Id 0", "Identifier", null);
```

Which returns : INTEL   SSDSCKKF512H6   LBF

While this works perfect form my system, "Target Id" seems to have different digit identifier for other system. how would I go about to detect the specific target ID (maybe detect it by using part of the registry subkey string, somehow).
Not even sure this will do the job for other type of disks (Nvme or IDE).
If there is a better way to do this without WMi query.

Thanks in advance

Found  something from CMD:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\Scsi\Scsi Port 0\Scsi Bus 0\Target Id 0" /v Identifier /s
```

This searches for the registry key named Identifier within Target Id 0

Comment: edited my question because it seems I wasn't clear about what I meant when I said "caption"

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SystemBootDevice` gives you the boot device, but it is not clear how that can be translated with certainty to a device.

Comment: it can't be translated

Comment: But worth considering, that SCSI location info is not the best starting point. This might also give you ideas: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\SCSI`

Comment: It's not that I don't like it...it's not even the correct place to search. The correct query would be for Win32_DiskDrive . The "Caption" property. The problem with it is that I would need to separate the system drive since this query will detect all the drives. As it stands on my PC that has multiple drives including a SSD it takes few seconds untill they all get enumerated.

Comment: The registry approach definitively does not work on all system, e.g. it returns the wrong drive caption on my box since the system is not installed on Unit 0.

Comment: That's the only thing that changes from system to system : target unit id #. I was hopping that there is a way to retrieve that # and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, then try:

This optimized version executes in ~65 ms on my system. That should be good enough.

```
//ManagementObject sys = new ManagementObject("Win32_OperatingSystem=@");
//string systemDrive = sys["SystemDrive"].ToString();
//Console.WriteLine("System Drive is {0}", systemDrive);

string strQuery = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" 
                + System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory).Replace("\\", "") 
                + "\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
RelatedObjectQuery relquery = new RelatedObjectQuery(strQuery);
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(relquery);
UInt32 ndx = 0;
foreach (var diskPartition in search.Get())
{
    ndx = (uint)diskPartition["DiskIndex"];
    Console.WriteLine("Disk Index of System Drive is {0}, Disk Partition is {1}", ndx, diskPartition["DeviceID"]);
}

SelectQuery diskQuery = new SelectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Index={0}", ndx));
ManagementObjectSearcher diskSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(diskQuery);
foreach (var disk in diskSearch.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caption is {0}", disk["Caption"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Serial Number is {0}", disk["SerialNumber"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Model is {0}", disk["Model"]);
    Console.WriteLine("InterfaceType is {0}", disk["InterfaceType"]);
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in the question, wmi query is easier to do and it works, but with huge it hitch: it's slower than a getting the value from the registry. I'm concerned about speed because I have the info displayed in a textbox located on a page in my app. each time I navigate to that page it takes 1-1.5 seconds to load it and that is a on a good computer.

Comment: @erma86 You said: "The problem with it (WMI) is that I would need to separate the system drive since this query will detect all the drives." The code I've provided only searches the system disk. If this is still not good enough fetch the value (in a separate thread if you like) when the app starts and store its value (it won't change anyway).

Comment: that's an ideea, but I wouldn't even know where to start to accomplish that. the situation is a little complicated. The texbox the info is displayed in is on a page containted in the main window....maybe I'll have to ask that as new question